# Simple If Statement

Tags: android, comparison, instance

I am trying to pass two variables from one screen to another. From the previous screeen you click a button, 1 or 2 and it passes that value on. It also passes the value 2 as the correct value. I know they are both working as I output each variable on the next screen. Here is the code. It always outputs wrong though.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
String newText = b.getString("PICKED");
String correct = b.getString("CORRECT");
TextView titles = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
if(newText == correct){
titles.setText("Correct" + newText + " " + correct + "");
}
else{
    titles.setText("Wrong" + newText + " " + correct + "");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you are not comparing the string.  you are comparing if both are pointing to same object.

to compare string use

```
if(nexText.equals(correct))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(newText == correct)
```

This will always be false. To compare the contents of two Strings character by character, use the .equals method:

```
if( newText.equals(correct) )
```

Using == on objects in Java means you are comparing the values of the memory address stored in these pointers/references. Since they are different String objects, they will never have the same address.

Answer (score 0):

You don't compare Strings this way, rewrite code this way to get things done:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
String newText = b.getString("PICKED");
String correct = b.getString("CORRECT");
TextView titles = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
if(newText.equals(correct)){
titles.setText("Correct" + newText + " " + correct + "");
}
else{
  titles.setText("Wrong" + newText + " " + correct + "");
}
```